# Why is this .NET 7 minimal api complaining that it cannot model bind from a body? It thinks it should model bind from a querystring

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, minimal-apis

Why is the .NET 7 minimal api throwing a run time error for the following `POST` endpoint?

> Required parameter "Guid fooId" was not provided from query string.

It is trying to model bind to a `querystring` instead of the post 'body'. Yes, I *know* I can fix this with a `[FromBody]` attribute, but why can't it figure this out?

```
subscriptionsGroup.MapPost("/verify/foo", PostVerifyFooAsync);

...

private static async Task<Ok> PostVerifyFooAsync(
    Guid fooId,
    string data
    //IMediator mediator,
    //CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    )
{
    return TypedResults.Ok();
}
```

as suggested, here's a sample POST query that's doing this. Notice how the body is JSON:

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:5000/testing/verify/foo' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "fooId": "11111111-fb03-4f5a-a7cb-b65c0581d7ac",
    "data": "testing 1 2 3"
}
```

so this is a `POST` with a JSON "raw" body. the `Content-Type` is provided so the framework knows this will be json in/json out.

Comment: try thiis [FromQuery], also how are you sending the request, you should send as josn to model bind it

Comment: And your query is?

Comment: Ah sorry. i forgot to include the CURL or request payload. i'll update the OP

Comment: Don't apply [FromBody] to more than one parameter per action method --- from [his document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#frombody-attribute). generally we define a model which containing all the properties required inside it. In your code sample, it just matches the sample at the beginning of the document

Answer (score 0):

Please allow me to post my test result here. Firstly, I have my mini-api like what OP has, then in the default swagger ui, I test like this, the post request url should be `https://localhost:7253/verify/foo?fooId=ebb018ce-b79d-4848-b4d5-cf648668c1a2&data=hello`

[image]

Then reproducing the issue in postman via url `https://localhost:7253/verify/foo?data=hello`

[image]
[image]